# Setting ENABLED to property_false for combo box list item does not alter the prompt foreground color

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

Using Oracle Form Builder 10.1.2.3.0, I have a `List Item` of type `Combo Box` with a `Prompt` and next to it in the same `Block` is a `CheckBox`.

When I disable these two items with

```
SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('block.item', ENABLED, PROPERTY_FALSE);
```

the `CheckBox` and its prompt go gray but the prompt portion of the `List Item` does not change. This makes the form and its developer look ridiculous.

Is this a bug?

To accomplish what I want I have to execute these when the `List Item`'s enablement changes:

```
set_item_property('block.item', foreground_color, 'r150g150b150')
set_item_property('block.item', foreground_color, 'r70g70b70')
```

And these are just guesses because the color meter app is not perfect.

Half of the problem would "go away" if I could use a visual attribute but the form builder app complains about the "gray" color not being named.

Surely there is a better solution. Maybe playing with the LAF? But I have yet to figure out LAF customization.

Answer (score 0):

I would not expect the prompt to change, but the edit area where text is entered will change.  There is one exception. If running with colorScheme SWAN or BLAF the text edit are will always remain white unless you explicitly change the color.  This is expected behavior.

If you are using SWAN or BLAF, which EBS does, by setting readOnlyBackground=true you can cause the edit area to go from white to a non-white color (the exact color will depend on the colorscheme in use). Because this parameter is not in the config by default it would need to be added manually and also added to the html template file.

Comment: The prompt changes for checkboxes (as I said in my OP) so why not all controls? It's natural. To have each control type behave differently is unwise.